# How to Add Route53 alias for CfnDistribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

Amazon has [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-route53-readme.html) for how to create a custom alias for your `CloudFrontWebDistribution`:

```
import route53 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-route53');
import targets = require('@aws-cdk/aws-route53-targets');

new route53.AaaaRecord(this, 'Alias', {
  zone: myZone,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.CloudFrontTarget(distribution))
});
```

Which looks super simple.

However, because of Lambda@Edge restrictions, I'm forced to use the low-level `CfnDistribution` instead.  Is there any way to create an alias for that one?  Either direcly or with some voodoo to create a high-level `CloudFrontWebDistribution` construct from a low-level `CfnDistribution`?

Comment: Can you share your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

I extracted the `CloudFrontTarget` code from the `aws-route53-targets` module and tweaked it to make this:

```
class CfnDistributionTarget implements route53.IAliasRecordTarget {
  private readonly distribution: CfnDistribution
  /**
   * The hosted zone Id if using an alias record in Route53.
   * This value never changes.
   */
  static readonly CLOUDFRONT_ZONE_ID = 'Z2FDTNDATAQYW2'
  constructor(distribution) {
    this.distribution = distribution
  }
  bind(_record: route53.IRecordSet): AliasRecordTargetConfig {
    return {
      hostedZoneId: CfnDistributionTarget.CLOUDFRONT_ZONE_ID,
      dnsName: this.distribution.attrDomainName
    }
  }
}
```